# Show list fields side-by-side when New/Edit/View in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation

It is possible to show fields in customized view for fields in a list? OOB feature show all columns one after one. But I want to show user customized way. like see below image

[image]

Is possible to do in Sharepoint 2013 foundation?. Any developed feature available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using `SharePoint Designer 2013`( its free :-) ). For this,

1. Open the site which contains the list in SharePoint Designer 2013.
2. Select the List from List and Libraries section.
3. Select your list.
4. Under the forms section, click on `New`.
5. On the popup, provide your form name and select New\Edit\Display.
6. Check the `set as default form....` checkbox and click on 'Ok'.
7. Now a form will be opened. You can change its layout as you want and save the changes.